# Is there an reliable method to control for angles when working with multiple consecutive actions in one scene?

Tags: animation, nla-editor, actions

Currently, I am working on an **animation where a character walks then turns at a 90 degree angle to the right then moves into the idle animation using a transition**. **All X,Y,Z rotation start at 0** for the following action sequence: Walk>Turn Right>Idle. However, the idle animation that follows is not turned in the same direction as the right turn animation. I tried turning the the idle animation using an object rotation on the Z-axis however, doing so messes up the transition between the to actions due to inconsistent angles between the idle and turning animation. I tried applying the rotation to zero out the angles after rotating the idle animation but that didn't work. Additionally, since it is a a Mixamo rig, I tried deleting the rotation in the hip bone, and used the empty I used for the walking animation to turn the rig for the turn animation; this worked to transition between the turn and idle animation, but the empty tended to mess up the animations for the rest of the actions down the line. So, then I created a new action using a previous action, but that didn't register as a new action as I could see the keyframes from the last time I used that action. So now I face the following problems when I implemented the previous method, actions  are now facing the wrong direction and are not sitting on the empty anymore. Is there a better way of controlling for angles in a scene with multiple animations? Any help with this would be helpful. The only solution I can think of is using multiple empties, which doesn't seem practical.